# Screen recording option is missing from Security&Privacy

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mojave, security, screen-recording

I was trying to test Teamviewer and found out that my option to disable/enable screen recording is missing. (see picture)

[image]

I have tried to reboot but it didn't help. Googling around did not come up with any useful info either.

My OS: 10.14.6

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Are you sure that it’s gonna be in Full Disk access? I would guess it would be in Accessibility or Photos.

Comment: @Todd that's just a coincidence that they have FDA tab open. The thing is that screen recording is a whole new tab that is missing here. ikel: try recording with quicktime & see what permissions appear.

Comment: @ankii That makes more sense. I didn't remember how it was on Mojave.

Comment: @ikel You can try Safe Boot to isolate issues with your Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Control of Screen Recording as a Privacy option was not available under Mojave (10.14) - this [Apple KB lists](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-privacy-preferences-on-mac-mh32356/10.14/mac/10.14) available controls.

The Screen Recording control appears for Catalina (10.15).

Only Microphone permission is required for screen recorders, if they ask. Test it using QuickTime Player.

Comment: I didn’t know screen recording is only for 10.15, great help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

What about a software that request this permission like Screegle (it is a screen sharing software)?

Screenshot:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wcHOEi5GgYrEwXngbOVwPKfieZXwbPHE/view?usp=share_link

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).